# How to separate string by '\n' in DolphinDB

Tags: string, dolphindb

```
x=`IBM`GOOG`APPL
```

I have the above variable.How can I get x like the following?

```
IBM
GOOG
APPL
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `contact` to merge all strings in a vector with a given delimiter

```
x=`IBM`GOOG`APPL
concat(x, "\n")
```